# Right border of div being cut off when using float:right with font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle of the below code](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/bZbn9/)

** Update: The border shows in Firefox but not Chrome. **

CSS:

```
.right{
    float:right;
}
.buttonBorder{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>11 in stock!</span>
    <span class="buttonBorder">Add to <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <span>11 in stock!</span>
    <span class="buttonBorder">Add to <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

The first div is not being floated to the right.  When I do float the div to the right, it cuts off the border.  I've tried adding margin-right and padding-right to the div, span and i elements and it doesn't appear to work.

How do I make the span show the border when the div is floated to the right?

Comment: It's strange, but I do see the the border on the right:

http://tinypic.com/r/dfd01y/8

Comment: @Medda86 - margin-right: 1px to what element?

Comment: @dgp - it looks like it works in FireFox but not Chrome

Comment: I saw you need width on the .right element... you have to put .right{width:200px;
    text-align:right;}

Comment: @Medda86 - that worked.  If you put that in the answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Whats the difference between my and @Medda86?

Comment: I can read thanks! Text-align is used to align 'text' not an element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we go :)

```
.right{
float:right;
width:200px;
text-align:right;}
```

Answer (score 2):

class .fa sets display:inline-block

override .fa for floated elements:

```
.right .fa{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use

```
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

And works good for me!

See my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/bZbn9/2/)

Comment: This worked as well but it caused the div element to be wide and didn't right align anymore.